# Google Sheets Gradebook for teacher - can this be done?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I apologize if this is not allowed or too general or vague.

I am a teacher frustrated by the fact that I cannot find a pre-made Google Sheets gradebook to do what I want.  I decided to try to write one myself.  Of course I not great at writing script but through trial and error and trying to decipher others code I am picking it up.

What I really want to know... is it possible to do what I envision or am I wasting my time?

I want to have a list of students in column 1 and enter an assignment title, type of assignment (there are 3 with different weights) and grade for each student in subsequent columns.. and be able to display a running cumulative grade based upon weighting - I know all of this can be done.  The extra part is being able to send the student and parent an email if an individual assignment grade is lower than a 70.  I am pretty sure this can be done.  The part I don't know is what that would look like. For instance, would there be a run script button that needs to be added for every assignment column in the spread sheet or....

I hope this makes sense and again apologize for my noobishness..

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: This can be done through the GmailApp class and Simple Triggers in Google Apps Script, can you share a sheet example? that will make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.groovypost.com/howto/google-sheets-send-email-based-on-cell-value/amp/
Your goal sounds doable assuming you are sending these mails from your gmail address or your org is using enterprise gmail.

Only other concern id say to watch out for is accidentally sending the emails out over and over for the same grade event.

As a student, if i recieved a recurring daily email about the same low grade assignment a month ago i might eventually spam flag the source, invalidating all that hard work.

Comment: Thanks - I had found that same page.  i am sending from gmail and I did not want to send the grade email for the same assignment each time - That is the part I am not sure can be done..

Comment: Maybe a triggerfield for the email that isnt the grade itself?. Like if <field> = 1 send email. Make the field start at 0. Then plus 1 to that field every time the grade in that column is found to match below 70. It will only ever = 1 one time. Then itll count up forever